# How to setup media-server on ubuntu watch movies on mobile in local network and from internet?

Tags: networking, android, remote, remote-access, mediaserver

I want to setup a media-server to store movies and videos in Ubuntu and play and watch them on a mobile device or a tablet. What i have to do to make that happen ?

Comment: You have a GUI or Ubuntu server edition? Also what Ubuntu version?

Comment: Gui and sorry for the trouble i found an awesome free software plex it works seamlessly. Thanks fot the feedback

Comment: I was going to suggest plex :) Thats why I asked about the gui, please consider writing an answer about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an solution i downloaded plex from plex.tv it is awesome and free it is just what i wanted and very easy to setup :)

**14.04 and below**

```
sudo apt-get install plex
```

**15.10 and 16.04**

[Download here](https://plex.tv/)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Kodi (xmbc) is a far better solution in my opinion. It takes some set up but the possibilities are endless including adding your own personal pvr. Also has integration with trakt, YouTube and hundreds of other addons! In other works it rocks! Check it out [here!](https://kodi.tv/)

Comparison between [Plex and Kodi](http://www.htpcbeginner.com/plex-vs-kodi-comparison-guide/)